# C# binary search tree

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I was making a test case for some code on binary search tree my professor gave

```
public static void Main(string [] args)
{
    //on my prof's code, public class BinSearchTree<T>
    BinSearchTree<int> myTree = new BinSearchTree<int>();

    myTree.Insert(10);
    myTree.Insert(15);
    myTree.Insert(5);
    myTree.Insert(2);
    myTree.Insert(1);

    Console.WriteLine(myTree.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It compiles, but it displays

`` BinSearchTree`1[System.Int32] ``

Can somebody tell me why it displays that?

my prof's code:

```
public class BinSearchTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
private class OurTreeNode<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public OurTreeNode<T> Left;
    public OurTreeNode<T> Right;
    public OurTreeNode(T d = default(T), OurTreeNode<T> leftnode = null, OurTreeNode<T> rightnode = null)
    {
        Data = d;
        Left = leftnode;
        Right = rightnode;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }
}
//...other methods

//prof's Insert method
public void Insert(T newItem)
{
    mRoot = Insert(newItem, mRoot);
}
private OurTreeNode<T> Insert(T newItem, OurTreeNode<T> pTmp)
{
    if (pTmp == null)
        return new OurTreeNode<T>(newItem, null, null);
    else if (newItem.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) < 0)
        pTmp.Left = Insert(newItem, pTmp.Left);
    else if (newItem.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) > 0)
        pTmp.Right = Insert(newItem, pTmp.Right);
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("...");

    return pTmp;
}
}
```

I tried adding a ToString() method after the Insert method but it gives me an error when I used foreach. Is there a way of displaying it without making too much extra methods?

Comment: a Data class was not provided. Do I have to make one?

Comment: Just loop all of your TreeNodes and print the Data property in which you store your values.

Comment: @Angela - See, you got the answer for now. But, to understand them, please prepare your own code for how to print the nodes of a binary-search-tree.

Comment: @Angela - Also, you didn't show the ToString() of BinSearchTree<T>, instead you showed the ToString() of OurTreeNode<T>!

Comment: You need to show us what you “tried adding” and what error it gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The class is using the default (Object's) ToString() implementation. You have 2 options:

- walk though the elements of the tree and print it yourself
- ask the author to implement/override the ToString() method

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody tell me why it displays that?

It displays that because [`ToString()` prints the type definition.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type. (from the docs)

For instance, the following short program prints `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] ``, which is the type of `List<int>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> myTree = new List<int>();
        myTree.Add(10);
        Console.WriteLine(myTree.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Here are the rudiments of how to override the `ToString()`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zzf6IM) method to produce some meaningful output.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinSearchTree<int> myTree = new BinSearchTree<int>();
        myTree.Insert(10);
        myTree.Insert(15);
        Console.WriteLine(myTree.ToString());
    }
}

public class BinSearchTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private List<T> values = new List<T>();

    // rest of class omitted for clarity

    public void Insert(T val) {
        values.Add(val);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        var result = string.Empty;
        foreach(var v in values)
        {
            result += v + ", ";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Output

```
10, 15,
```

Comment: is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: @Angela Yes. You need to override `ToString()`. See edits.

Comment: I edited the code above. my prof already has an insert method on his code and I tried to add a ToString method but foreach gives an error

Answer (score 0):

As you have created the object of `BinaryTree` Class and have not overridden the `ToString()` method inside BinaryTree Class. You have not created object of `OurTreeNode` class and not calling `ToString()` method overriden inside it. Hence it is giving you the default `ToString()` method output of BinaryTree Class.

```
BinSearchTree<int> myTree = new BinSearchTree<int>();
```

You are calling

```
Console.WriteLine(myTree.ToString());
```